# Translate Excel Formula to Power Query

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerquery

In my Power Query I have a column that shows different durations on certain items,  but it displays an error when attempting to convert on time or duration.

As a solution next to my Excel Table I created a formula that alows to convert the duration in the format I wish to use, but I have not been able to translate the formula into a language that Power Query can understand (I am pretty new to Power Query).

**This is how the data is pulled from source:**

[image]

**But I will like it to show like this:**

[image]

The Excel Formula I am using to accomplish this is:

```
=IF(LEN([@Age])=7,"0"&[@Age],IF(LEN([@Age])=5,"00:"&[@Age],IF(LEN([@Age])=4,"00:0"&[@Age],IF(LEN([@Age])=3,"00:00"&[@Age],[@Age]))))
```

It will be nice to have it in the Power Query instead of the Excel sheet, as it serves as a learning oportunity.

I am self learning Power Query in Excel so any help is welcomed.

EDIT: In Case of the duration being more than 24:00:00,  how will i approach it

[image]

Here is the error code it returns

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a custom column with the formula:

```
Duration.FromText(
            Text.Combine(
                List.LastN(
                    {"00"} & List.ReplaceValue(Text.Split([Age],":"),"","00",Replacer.ReplaceValue),
                        3),
            ":"))
```

The formula

- Splits the text string by the colon into a List
- Replacing blanks with `{00}` and also prepend the list with a `{00}` element
- Retrieve the last three elements and combine them into a colon separated text string.
- Use `Duration.FromText` function to convert to a duration.
- Set the data type of the column to `duration`

In the PQ Editor, a duration will have the format of `d.hh:mm:ss`, but when you load it back into Excel, you can change that to `[hh]:mm:ss`

You can accomplish the above all in the PQ User Interface.

Here is `M-Code` that does the same thing:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table16"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Age", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Duration", each Duration.FromText(
            Text.Combine(
                List.LastN(
                    {"00"} & List.ReplaceValue(Text.Split([Age],":"),"","00",Replacer.ReplaceValue),
                        3),
            ":"))),
            
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Age"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

You can even do it (using M-Code in the Advanced Editor) without adding a column by using the `Table.TransformColumns` function:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table16"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Age", type text}}),
 
    #"Change to Duration" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type",
        {"Age", each Duration.FromText(
            Text.Combine(
                List.LastN(
                    {"00"} & List.ReplaceValue(Text.Split(_,":"),"","00",Replacer.ReplaceValue),
                        3),
            ":")), type duration})
in
    #"Change to Duration"
```

All result in:

[image]

***Edit***
With your modified data, now showing duration values of more than 23 hours (not allowed in a duration literal in PQ), the transformation will be different.  We have to check the hours and break it into days and hours if it is more than 23.

***Note: the below edit also assumes there will never be anything entered in the `day` location; and that entries for minutes and seconds will always be within range. If there might be `day` values, you will need to just add what's there to the "overflow" from the hours entry***

So we change the Custom Column formula to check for that:

```
let 
            split = List.LastN({"00","00"} & List.ReplaceValue(Text.Split([Age],":"),"","00",Replacer.ReplaceValue),4),
            s = Number.From(List.Last(split)),
            m = Number.From(List.LastN(split,2){0}),
            hTotal = Number.From(List.LastN(split,3){0}),
            h = Number.Mod(hTotal,24),
            d = Number.IntegerDivide(hTotal,24)
        in #duration(d,h,m,s)
```

[image]

*If you might have illegal values for minutes or seconds, you can add logig to check for that also*

*Also, if you will be loading this into Excel, and you might have total days >31, you will need to format it (in Excel), as `[hh]:mm:ss` as with the format `d.hh:mm:ss` Excel cannot display more than 31 days (although the proper value will be stored in the cell)*

Comment: Thanks! that is actually what i was looking for,  I tested it out and it worked but  it returns and error when the Age shows  46:00:00,  596:00:00 , in those scenarios chaing the format should fix it? Added a Screenshot of the error

Comment: @RichardFowler See my edit, and read the caveats

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, i was able to  obtain the expected results. As the data was HH:MM:SS  all the time Day will not be filled.   Thanks!